# How to get a Lookup as Union of 2 old Lookups?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can you get a Lookup from a Union of 2 old Lookups? Seems like `a = a.Union(b)` does not work for them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have the original lists that the lookups came from, it might be easier.  It might also be easier if you used `Dictionary`s of `Lists` instead of lookups.  However, it's still possible to merge two lookup objects into a new object.  The basic idea is to retrieve the original values from the lookups, and then create a new lookup from the concatenated set of both.

```
var a = new[] {"apple","aardvark","barn"};
var b = new[] {"baboon", "candy", "cork"};

var al = a.ToLookup (x => x[0]);
var bl = b.ToLookup (x => x[0]);

var cl = al.Concat(bl).SelectMany(x => x).ToLookup(x => x[0]);
```

If you also don't know the original key selector function, you can use this variant.

```
var cl = al.Concat(bl)
    .SelectMany(lookup => lookup.Select(value => new { lookup.Key, value}))
    .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.value);
```

Comment: What if I have no refs to any of the collections used in LookUp creation?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as the OP however the above code doesn't help me - the fact you are repeating the keySelector definition rather than using the grouping.Key to create the lookups. I was hoping for more generic code using the keys of each incoming lookup.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this extension method, which takes advantage of the fact that an `ILookup<TK,TV>` is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TK,TV>>`

```
    public static ILookup<TK, TV> Union<TK, TV>(this ILookup<TK, TV> self, IEnumerable<IGrouping<TK,TV>> moreGroupings)
    {
        return self.Concat(moreGroupings)
            .SelectMany(grouping => grouping.Select(val => new KeyValuePair<TK, TV>(grouping.Key, val)))
            .ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
    }
```

Here are a few tests that demonstrate. The lookups here contain strings, keyed by their lengths.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void EmptyLookups_UnionReturnsEmpty()
    {
        var a = new string[] { }.ToLookup(x => x.Length, x => x);
        var b = new string[] { }.ToLookup(x => x.Length, x => x);
        var c = a.Union(b);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, c.Count);
        c = b.Union(a);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, c.Count);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OneEmptyLookup_UnionReturnsContentsOfTheOther()
    {
        var a = new string[] { }.ToLookup(x => x.Length, x => x);
        var b = new string[] { "hello", "world" }.ToLookup(x => x.Length, x => x);
        var c = a.Union(b);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, c.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("helloworld", string.Join("", c[5].OrderBy(x=>x)));
        c = b.Union(a);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, c.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("helloworld", string.Join("", c[5].OrderBy(x=>x)));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void UniqueKeys_UnionAdds()
    {
        var a = new string[] { "cat", "frog", "elephant"}.ToLookup(x => x.Length, x => x);
        var b = new string[] { "hello", "world" }.ToLookup(x => x.Length, x => x);
        var c = a.Union(b);
        Assert.AreEqual(4, c.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("cat", string.Join("", c[3]));
        Assert.AreEqual("frog", string.Join("", c[4]));
        Assert.AreEqual("elephant", string.Join("", c[8]));
        Assert.AreEqual("helloworld", string.Join("", c[5].OrderBy(x=>x)));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OverlappingKeys_UnionMerges()
    {
        var a = new string[] { "cat", "frog", "horse", "elephant"}.ToLookup(x => x.Length, x => x);
        var b = new string[] { "hello", "world" }.ToLookup(x => x.Length, x => x);
        var c = a.Union(b);
        Assert.AreEqual(4, c.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("cat", string.Join("", c[3]));
        Assert.AreEqual("frog", string.Join("", c[4]));
        Assert.AreEqual("elephant", string.Join("", c[8]));
        Assert.AreEqual("hellohorseworld", string.Join("", c[5].OrderBy(x=>x)));
    }
```

I also happen to need to handle case-insensitive strings, so I have this overload that takes a custom comparer.

```
        public static ILookup<TK, TV> Union<TK, TV>(this ILookup<TK, TV> self, IEnumerable<IGrouping<TK,TV>> moreGroupings, IEqualityComparer<TK> comparer)
    {
        return self.Concat(moreGroupings)
            .SelectMany(grouping => grouping.Select(val => new KeyValuePair<TK, TV>(grouping.Key, val)))
            .ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value, comparer);
    }
```

The lookups in these examples use the first letter as a key:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void OverlappingKeys_CaseInsensitiveUnionAdds()
    {
        var a = new string[] { "cat", "frog", "HORSE", "elephant"}.ToLookup(x => x.Substring(0,1), x => x);
        var b = new string[] { "hello", "world" }.ToLookup(x => x.Substring(0,1), x => x);
        var c = a.Union(b, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.AreEqual(6, c.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("cat", string.Join("", c["c"]));
        Assert.AreEqual("frog", string.Join("", c["f"]));
        Assert.AreEqual("elephant", string.Join("", c["e"]));
        Assert.AreEqual("hello", string.Join("", c["h"].OrderBy(x=>x)));
        Assert.AreEqual("HORSE", string.Join("", c["H"].OrderBy(x=>x)));
        Assert.AreEqual("world", string.Join("", c["w"]));
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void OverlappingKeys_CaseSensitiveUnionMerges()
    {
        var a = new string[] { "cat", "frog", "HORSE", "elephant"}.ToLookup(x => x.Substring(0,1), x => x);
        var b = new string[] { "hello", "world" }.ToLookup(x => x.Substring(0,1), x => x);
        var c = a.Union(b, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, c.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("cat", string.Join("", c["c"]));
        Assert.AreEqual("frog", string.Join("", c["f"]));
        Assert.AreEqual("elephant", string.Join("", c["e"]));
        Assert.AreEqual("helloHORSE", string.Join("", c["h"].OrderBy(x=>x)));
        Assert.AreEqual("helloHORSE", string.Join("", c["H"].OrderBy(x=>x)));
        Assert.AreEqual("world", string.Join("", c["w"]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

one can consider more flexible way for any count of array/list. For example, create synonym's lookup:

```
public ILookup<string, string> GetSynonyms()
{
    var data = new[]
        {
            new[] {"hello", "hi there", "привет"},
            new[] {"bye", "Tchau", "Adios"},
            new[] {"hello", "hi there"}
        };

    return data
        .SelectMany(words => words.SelectMany(
            keyWord => words.Where(word => word != keyWord).Select(word => new Tuple<string, string>(item1: keyWord, item2: word))))
        .Distinct(comparer: new DelegateComparer<Tuple<string, string>>(equals: Equals, hashCode: v => v.GetHashCode()))
        .ToLookup(keySelector: k => k.Item1, elementSelector: e => e.Item2);
}

public sealed class DelegateComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _equals;
    private readonly Func<T, int> _hashCode;

    public DelegateComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals, Func<T, int> hashCode)
    {
        _equals = equals;
        _hashCode = hashCode;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _hashCode != null ? _hashCode(obj) : obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

[image: result of execution]